# SQL query to count widgets of a certain type missing a transaction of a certain type

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm building an SQL query in MS Access 2010. The business problem is:

> All widgets of type 'A' should have a corresponding inspection
>   transaction record of type 'internal' in the inspections table.  However, some 'A' widgets do not yet have an inspection transaction record of type 'internal' in the inspection
>   table. Write a SQL query to count the number of widgets of type 'A'
>   which are missing an 'internal' inspection transaction.

There are three tables:

1. **widgets** (the primary widget table)
2. **widget_info** (the table holding a number of widget attributes, including the widget type)
3. **inspections** (a transactional table of inspection records, which may contain several inspection records for each widget... one of which MAY be of type 'internal')

The query should return a count of widgets that show as of type 'A' in the widget_info table and do NOT have a record in the inspections table of type 'internal'. Note that the inspection table may include several records for each widget that NOT of type 'internal', i.e., there me be a 'prelim' inspection record or an 'external' inspection record.

My best stab at this is:

```
SELECT Count(widgets.*) AS count
FROM (widgets 
INNER JOIN widget_info 
    ON widget_info.widget_number = widgets.widget_number) 
INNER JOIN inspections 
    ON inspections.widget_number = widgets.widget_number
WHERE widget_info.type ='A' AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inspections WHERE inspections.type <> 'internal')
```

I get a zero count when I execute the query, even though I know that there are widgets missing 'internal' inspections.

Thank you for you time!

Bob

Comment: use left join on inspections

Comment: @artm, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried it but it still returns a zero result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue with this query was that the WHERE clause of the NOT EXISTS() function did not include a condition to match the widget number between the widget table and the inspection table.  I modified the query as follows, and it worked.

```
SELECT Count(widgets.*) AS count
FROM (widgets 
INNER JOIN widget_info 
    ON widget_info.widget_number = widgets.widget_number) 
INNER JOIN inspections 
    ON inspections.widget_number = widgets.widget_number
WHERE widget_info.type ='A' AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inspections WHERE inspections.type <> 'internal'
    AND inspections.widget_number = widgets.widget_number);
```